# Chartjs new data

Tags: chart.js

I got the desired result for the new Chartjs data.
I've been at this for a while and finally got it right after some research and advice.

Now I can display my data in real time..

Can you help me suggest a code optimization to display the chart in real time with chartjs?

```
const ctx = $("#chart_c6e38976");
const data = {
    labels: [],
    datasets: [{
        label: "",
        data: [],
        pointStyle: "circle",
        pointRadius: 5,
        pointHoverRadius: 10
    }]
};
const options = {
    scales: {
        x: {
            display: false,
        },
        y: {
            display: true,
        }
    },
    responsive: true
};
const config = {
    type: "line",
    data: data,
    options
};
const myChart = new Chart (
    ctx,
    config
);
function addData( chart, label, data ) {
    chart.data.labels.push( label );
    chart.data.datasets.forEach(( dataset ) => {
        dataset.data.push( data );
    } );
    chart.update();
}
function addNewData( chart, label, data, new_label ) {
    chart.data.labels[label] = new_label;
    chart.data.datasets[0].data[label] = data;
    chart.update();
}
var getData = function() { 
    $.getJSON("http://localhost/creation-site-internet-tarn/ahiuho_ihfsf_521/data.php?grr=liste_lien", function (result) {
        $.each(result, function(i, field) {
            var count_length = result.length;
            if (data.labels.length < count_length) {
                addData(myChart, field.date_insert, field.count);
            } else {
                addNewData(myChart, count_length-1, field.count, field.date_insert);
                //myChart.data.datasets[0].data[count_length] = field.count;
                //myChart.data.labels[count_length] = field.date_insert;
                //myChart.update();
            }
        });

    });
}
setTimeout(getData, 1000);
setInterval(getData, 5000);
```

I hope it goes well.

Thank.